# Query builder - codeigniter

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, query-builder

I have problems building a query that uses three tables.

If I write the query as:

```
$query = "select domains.ID, domains.Name, domains.IP, 
database_info.DB_Name, database_info.DB_User, database_info.DB_Pass, 
ftp.FTP_User, ftp.FTP_Pass from domains
left join database_info on domains.ID = database_info.Domain_ID
left join ftp on domains.ID = ftp.Domain_ID
where domains.ID = $ID";

                $query = $this->db->get();
                if($query->num_rows()>0){
                    return $query->result();
                }
```

I get error Number 1096  No tables used SELECT *
However is I write the query using the query builder:

```
       $this->db->select('domains.ID','domains.Name','domains.IP',
       'database_info.DB_Name','database_info.DB_User',
       'database_info.DB_Pass','ftp.FTP_User','ftp.FTP_Pass');
        $this->db->from('domains');
        $this->db->join('database_info','domains.ID =
        database_info.Domain_ID', 'left');
        $this->db->join('ftp','domains.ID = ftp.Domain_ID','left');
        $this->db->where('domains.ID',$ID);
        $query = $this->db->get();
        if($query->num_rows()>0){
            return $query->result();
        }
```

The query runs but only returns the domains.ID
Open to ideas and suggests

Comment: I'd be reading the user guide again. Find out how to perform a query in your 1st example where you are basically defining a string and then attempting to get something back into the same variable. Hint - look at $this->db->query($query), In your 2nd instance, take a look at how to perform a Select :)  And you might find echo $this->db->get_compiled_select(); useful for quickly displaying the actual generated SQL which will show you the errors of your ways. Read up on that too.

Comment: Many thanks, first try with codeigniter so finding my feet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
$query = $this->db
    ->select('domains.ID,domains.Name,domains.IP, database_info.DB_Name,database_info.DB_User,database_info.DB_Pass,ftp.FTP_User,ftp.FTP_Pass')
    ->from('domains')
    ->join('database_info','domains.ID = database_info.Domain_ID', 'left')
    ->join('ftp','domains.ID = ftp.Domain_ID','left')
    ->where('domains.ID',$ID)
    ->get();
if($query->num_rows()>0)
{
    return $query->result();
}
```

The point is in your select statement - the Query Builder only accepts one argument for your entire select statement not that many as you did

> and please for the sake of security - never ever try to execute sql
>   statements without escaping them - CI's query builder will do this per
>   default - but your first example is pretty dangerous and widely open
>   to sql injections

Answer (score 0):

Use [**`db->query`**](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/results.html)

```
$sql = "select domains.ID, domains.Name, domains.IP, 
database_info.DB_Name, database_info.DB_User, database_info.DB_Pass, 
ftp.FTP_User, ftp.FTP_Pass from domains
left join database_info on domains.ID = database_info.Domain_ID
left join ftp on domains.ID = ftp.Domain_ID
where domains.ID = $ID";

$query = $this->db->query($sql);
$result = $query->result_array();
```

Follow the [CodeIgniter User Guide](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/index.html)